# Why moving plunger in cylindrical tube can be considered as plain stress condition?

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain

The plunger moves in the tube as you can see in the picture. This situation is plane strain, but i don't see it, i mean there are stresses in all directions so how is it possible to view this as plane stress condition? [image]

Comment: Is there air inside the cavity? It is a drag between the pieces? Please give more details.

Comment: @hyprfrcb insid is oil, but i don't think so the identity of substances inside tube has anything to do with plain stress or plain strain.

Comment: Maybe your teacher wants to solve it easily for a more suitable homework